# Ask for user input and replace values using a batch file

Tags: batch-file, command-line

In a windows batch file I want to ask the user for an input, for example: "What is your name: **jack** " and then replace ***newname*** with what the user input ***jack***.

**old file content**

```
first newname
second newname
oldfile/newname/
available/newname
newname
```

**new file content**

```
first jack
second jack
oldfile/jack/
available/jack
jack
```

Comment: [User's input _set /p_](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html) and [read file contents](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) and [replace](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html). Please share a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I used **variables**:

```
title Variables
set newinput=Default
echo Name of new Database:
set /p newinput=
```

Then replaced old data with the variable:

```
first %newinput%
second %newinput%
oldfile/%newinput%/
available/%newinput%
%newinput%
```

Then create a new file using what the user has input:

```
@echo off
title Variables
set newinput=Default
echo Name of new Database:
set /p newinput=
break>test.sh
@echo first %newinput%>> test.sh
@echo second %newinput%>> test.sh
@echo oldfile/%newinput%/'>> test.sh
@echo available/%newinput%>> test.sh
@echo %newinput%>> test.sh
```

Every time the batch file is ran and the user inputs something it changes the file.

Comment: I'm fairly certain you've added an unwanted leading space character here: `set newinput= Default`.